# Find Text Between two words in Java

Tags: search, text

I want to get all text in between 2 words wherver it is.
For example:

```
String Testing="one i am here fine two one hope your are also fine two one ok see you two";
```

From the above string, I want to fetch the words between "one" and "two" in array:

My result should be stored in array like this:

```
String result[1] = i am here fine
String result[2] = hope your are also fine  
String result[3] = ok see you
```

How to do in java?

Thanks in advance

- Gnaniyar Zubair

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
String input = "one i am here fine two one hope your are also fine two one ok see you two;";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\bone\\b).*?(?=\\btwo\\b)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find()) {
  matches.add(m.group());
}
```

This will create a List of all the text between "one" and "two".

If you want a simpler version that doesn't use lookaheads/lookbehinds try:

```
String input = "one i am here fine two one hope your are also fine two one ok see you two;";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\bone\\b)(.*?)(\\btwo\\b)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find()) {
  matches.add(m.group(2));
}
```

**Note:** Java arrays are zero-based not one-based so in your example the first result would be in `result[0]` not `result[1]`. In my solution, the first match is in `matches.get(0)`.

Comment: +1 Second regex is better, no need to use lookaround, especially lookbehind, unless you need to, it's an efficiency killer!

Comment: HI cletus, amazing thanks for your immediate response. thanks a lot.

Comment: I tried like this:
instead of "one", my starting values is :/c/document_library/get_file?
end value is ( instead of two): 
&groupId=

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\b/c/document_library/get_file?uuid=\\b)(.*?)(\\b&groupId=\\b)"); 
Matcher m = p.matcher(content); 
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>(); 
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find()) { 
  matches.add(m.group()); 
} 
     
for(int z=0; z<matches.size(); z++) {
    result.add(matches.get(z));
}
     System.out.println("result1 >>> = " + matches.get(0));

But i am getting Index =0 ; size = 0....

Comment: How can I match if say “one” and “two” contained special regex characters, escaping doesn’t seem to work… take a look at my question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/71741706/10138416

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way (written for Groovy shell), minus any error handling:

```
public String textBetweenWords(String sentence, String firstWord, String secondWord)
{
    return sentence.substring(sentence.indexOf(firstWord) + firstWord.length(), 
        sentence.indexOf(secondWord));
}

String between = textBetweenWords("Hello my dear cousin!", "Hello", "cousin");

println("[" + between + "]")
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Java [Pattern](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class that allows you to use regular expressions to identify substrings and consequently split up a larger string. You need something like

```
Pattern.compile("\bone\B");
```

to identify 'one'. The `\b` and `\B` are word boundary matches. You need these so you don't accidentally match on "someone" rather than the word "one" (as an aside, I'd recommend a different delimiter rather than the words "one", "two" etc.)

Answer (score -1):

Just use indexOf and subString Methods