# Extract substring where startString and endString are same

Tags: java, substring

I want to extract the sentence/word, where the start string and end string are same,
for example :

```
String originalString = "this is an example to extract sentence between is";
```

here start string and end string is same that is : `"is"`
So the final output should be : `an example to extract sentence between`

I tried as below, but it returned output as `"is"` only

```
 String originalString = "this is an example to extract sentence between is";
        String startEndString = "is";

        int startIndex = originalString.indexOf(startEndString);
        int endIndex = originalString.indexOf(startEndString, startIndex + startEndString.length());

        String substring = originalString.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
        System.out.println(substring);
```

I also checked `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils` substring methods, but could not find any to fulfill this type of extract. Is there any java8 / StringUtil method / API already available to do this job?

Comment: The first `indexOf("is")` will return `2` because `"this"` also contains `"is"`.

Comment: [Find Text Between two words in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988333/find-text-between-two-words-in-java) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, after changing this to something else like "there", then I am able to get desired output. However is there a way to extract even if "is" word is part of another word

Comment: If your start `String` is always a word, use a regular expression to break your sentences into words (`String` `split`), and then check the `String` array of words for your start word and end word.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the desired result using regex:

```
String originalString = "this is an example to extract sentence between is";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "(?<=(?:\\bis\\b))(.*)(?=(?:\\bis\\b))" );
Matcher m = p.matcher( originalString );
if ( m.find() ) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

`(?<=(?:\\bis\\b))` is a positive look behind, with a non capturing group. The word  you're looking for is placed between the boundary keywords `\b`. The boundaries make sure it will only look for whole words (so 'this' will be skipped). `(?=(?:\\bis\\b))` is a positive look ahead. The end result will be anything between the two groups.